# Javascript Filter Function in a For Loop

Tags: javascript

I was able to complete the task using .filter() and a For Loop, but not sure why I cannot use the format in my second example.  First example works fine.

```
function destroyer(arr) {

 for(i=1; i < arguments.length; i++){
   number = arguments[i];
   arr = arr.filter(function(num){
     return num !== number;
   });
  }
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Tried to replace the `return num !== number;` with `return num!==arguments[i]` but the `arguments[i]` does not appear to return the numeric value.

Comment: The `arguments` object inside the filter callback is for *that* function, and will be different from the `arguments` object in the surrounding function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `arguments` refers to a different functions arguments at that point.

Every time you enter a function, `arguments` will refer to the *currently executing functions arguments*. It wouldn't make much sense for `arguments` to only refer to the top-level functions arguments.

Example:

```js
function a() {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  var b = function() {
    console.log(arguments[0]);
  };
  b('This is b');
}

a('This is a');
```

Comment: I was not looking at it from that perspective, where the second function on the .Filter was involved.  Makes sense now.  Thanks.

Comment: @BradCunningham Sure thing! I remember having a similar issue with `arguments` at first haha.